# Alternative to lambda to directly store events in a store (sql, mongo, s3, w.e.)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suppose the requested functionality is as follows:

- Endpoint receives document in predefined shape
- The received document must be stored as is in long term storage (such as sql database, or document store, or s3, or w.e.)
- The endpoint must not block while storing - validation shall be done later.

Are there any solutions provided by AWS out of the box that do that already or am I stuck with defining a lambda for that?

Comment: This kind of questions is off-topic here, but you could look into Kinesis Firehose (if you need to buffer and/or batch your documents) or AWS Gateway with a native/HTTP integration (if you don't)